# How to sort by two fields in Java?

Tags: java, sorting

I have array of objects `person (int age; String name;)`.

How can I sort this array alphabetically by name and then by age?

Which algorithm would you use for this ?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

You can use `Collections.sort` as follows:

```
private static void order(List<Person> persons) {

    Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator() {

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            String x1 = ((Person) o1).getName();
            String x2 = ((Person) o2).getName();
            int sComp = x1.compareTo(x2);

            if (sComp != 0) {
               return sComp;
            } 

            Integer x1 = ((Person) o1).getAge();
            Integer x2 = ((Person) o2).getAge();
            return x1.compareTo(x2);
    }});
}
```

`List<Persons>` is now sorted by name, then by age.

`String.compareTo` "Compares two strings lexicographically" - from the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

`Collections.sort` is a static method in the native Collections library. It does the actual sorting, you just need to provide a Comparator which defines how two elements in your list should be compared: this is achieved by providing your own implementation of the `compare` method.

Comment: Mini code review: the else clause is redundant because the first return acts as a guard clause. Great answer though, worked a treat for me.

Comment: As this question/ answer still gets linked, please note that with Java SE 8 this became much simpler. If there are getters you can write `Comparator<Person> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).thenComparingInt(Person::getAge);`

Answer (score 196):

For those able to use the Java 8 streaming API, there is a neater approach that is well documented here:
[Lambdas and sorting](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/31/java-8-friday-goodies-lambdas-and-sorting/)

I was looking for the equivalent of the C# LINQ:

```
.ThenBy(...)
```

I found the mechanism in Java 8 on the Comparator:

```
.thenComparing(...)
```

So here is the snippet that demonstrates the algorithm.

```
    Comparator<Person> comparator = Comparator.comparing(person -> person.name);
    comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(person -> person.age));
```

Check out the link above for a neater way and an explanation about how Java's type inference makes it a bit more clunky to define compared to LINQ.

Here is the full unit test for reference:

```
@Test
public void testChainedSorting()
{
    // Create the collection of people:
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(new Person("Dan", 4));
    people.add(new Person("Andi", 2));
    people.add(new Person("Bob", 42));
    people.add(new Person("Debby", 3));
    people.add(new Person("Bob", 72));
    people.add(new Person("Barry", 20));
    people.add(new Person("Cathy", 40));
    people.add(new Person("Bob", 40));
    people.add(new Person("Barry", 50));

    // Define chained comparators:
    // Great article explaining this and how to make it even neater:
    // http://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/31/java-8-friday-goodies-lambdas-and-sorting/
    Comparator<Person> comparator = Comparator.comparing(person -> person.name);
    comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(person -> person.age));

    // Sort the stream:
    Stream<Person> personStream = people.stream().sorted(comparator);

    // Make sure that the output is as expected:
    List<Person> sortedPeople = personStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    Assert.assertEquals("Andi",  sortedPeople.get(0).name); Assert.assertEquals(2,  sortedPeople.get(0).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Barry", sortedPeople.get(1).name); Assert.assertEquals(20, sortedPeople.get(1).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Barry", sortedPeople.get(2).name); Assert.assertEquals(50, sortedPeople.get(2).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Bob",   sortedPeople.get(3).name); Assert.assertEquals(40, sortedPeople.get(3).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Bob",   sortedPeople.get(4).name); Assert.assertEquals(42, sortedPeople.get(4).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Bob",   sortedPeople.get(5).name); Assert.assertEquals(72, sortedPeople.get(5).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Cathy", sortedPeople.get(6).name); Assert.assertEquals(40, sortedPeople.get(6).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Dan",   sortedPeople.get(7).name); Assert.assertEquals(4,  sortedPeople.get(7).age);
    Assert.assertEquals("Debby", sortedPeople.get(8).name); Assert.assertEquals(3,  sortedPeople.get(8).age);
    // Andi     : 2
    // Barry    : 20
    // Barry    : 50
    // Bob      : 40
    // Bob      : 42
    // Bob      : 72
    // Cathy    : 40
    // Dan      : 4
    // Debby    : 3
}

/**
 * A person in our system.
 */
public static class Person
{
    /**
     * Creates a new person.
     * @param name The name of the person.
     * @param age The age of the person.
     */
    public Person(String name, int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * The name of the person.
     */
    public String name;

    /**
     * The age of the person.
     */
    public int age;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        if (name == null) return super.toString();
        else return String.format("%s : %d", this.name, this.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the complexity of this sort of chaining of comparators? Are we essentially sorting each time we chain the comparators? So we do a NlogN operation for each comparator?

Comment: If there are getters you can write `Comparator<Person> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).thenComparing(Person::getAge);`

Comment: Use `thenComparingInt` for age (int)

Comment: Syntax with the labda '->' doesnt work for me. The Person::getLastName does.

Comment: After creating the comparator, what is the need to create a stream, sort it with the comparator and then collect it? Can you just use `Collections.sort(people, comparator);` instead?

Comment: There is only one sort - every time sort needs to compare 2 elements the provided comparator is used. And each `thenComparing` is only executed if previous one returned EQUAL/0.
And yes, `Collections.sort`  works with such comparators.

Answer (score 157):

Using the Java 8 Streams approach, with method references on the getters...

```
// Create a stream...
var sortedList = persons.stream()
    // sort it (does not sort the original list)...
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)
                      .thenComparing(Person::getAge));
    // and collect to a new list
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Collection to an array ist also possible:

```
persons.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)
                      .thenComparing(Person::getAge));
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

And the Java 8 Lambda approach...

```
//Sorts the original list Lambda style
persons.sort((p1, p2) -> {
        if (p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()) == 0) {
            return p1.getAge().compareTo(p2.getAge());
        } else {
            return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
        } 
    });
```

Lastly...

```
// This syntax is similar to the Streams example above, but sorts the original list!!!
persons.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).thenComparing(Person::getAge));
```

Answer (score 19):

You need to implement your own `Comparator`, and then use it: for example

```
Arrays.sort(persons, new PersonComparator());
```

Your Comparator could look a bit like this:

```
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<? extends Person> {

  public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
     int nameCompare = p1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(p2.name);
     if (nameCompare != 0) {
        return nameCompare;
     } else {
       return Integer.valueOf(p1.age).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(p2.age));
     }
  }
}
```

The comparator first compares the names, if they are not equals it returns the result from comparing them, else it returns the compare result when comparing the ages of both persons.

*This code is only a draft: because the class is immutable you could think of building an singleton of it, instead creating a new instance for each sorting.*

Answer (score 16):

Have your person class implement `Comparable<Person>` and then implement the compareTo method, for instance:

```
public int compareTo(Person o) {
    int result = name.compareToIgnoreCase(o.name);
    if(result==0) {
        return Integer.valueOf(age).compareTo(o.age);
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

That will sort first by name (case insensitively) and then by age. You can then run `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()` on the collection or array of Person objects.

Answer (score 6):

Guava's `ComparisonChain` provides a clean way of doing it. Refer to this [link](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html).

A utility for performing a chained comparison statement. For example:

```
   public int compareTo(Foo that) {
     return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
         .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
         .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
         .result();
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
List<User> users = Lists.newArrayList(
  new User("Pedro", 12), 
  new User("Maria", 10), 
  new User("Rafael",12)
);

users.sort(
  Comparator.comparing(User::getName).thenComparing(User::getAge)
);
```

Answer (score 5):

I would be careful when using Guava's `ComparisonChain` because it creates an instance of it per element been compared so you would be looking at a creation of `N x Log N` comparison chains just to compare if you are sorting, or `N` instances if you are iterating and checking for equality.

I would instead create a static `Comparator` using the newest Java 8 API if possible or Guava's `Ordering` API which allows you to do that, here is an example with Java 8:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;
import static java.util.Comparator.nullsLast;

private static final Comparator<Person> COMPARATOR = Comparator
  .comparing(Person::getName, nullsLast(naturalOrder()))
  .thenComparingInt(Person::getAge);

@Override
public int compareTo(@NotNull Person other) {
  return COMPARATOR.compare(this, other);
}
```

Here is how to use the Guava's `Ordering` API: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/OrderingExplained

Comment: "...creates an instance of it per element been compared..." -- this is not true. At least in modern versions of Guava, calling to `compare` method doesn't create anything, but returns one of singleton instances `LESS`, `GREATER` or `ACTIVE` depending on the result of the comparison. This is a highly optimized approach and doesn't add any memory or performance overhead.

Comment: Yes; I just looked at the source code now, I see what you mean, but I'd be more inclined to use the new Java 8 comparison API for the sake of dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Create as many comparators as necessary. After, call the method "thenComparing" for each order category. It's a way of doing by Streams. See:

```
//Sort by first and last name
System.out.println("\n2.Sort list of person objects by firstName then "
                                        + "by lastName then by age");
Comparator<Person> sortByFirstName 
                            = (p, o) -> p.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(o.firstName);
Comparator<Person> sortByLastName 
                            = (p, o) -> p.lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(o.lastName);
Comparator<Person> sortByAge 
                            = (p, o) -> Integer.compare(p.age,o.age);

//Sort by first Name then Sort by last name then sort by age
personList.stream().sorted(
    sortByFirstName
        .thenComparing(sortByLastName)
        .thenComparing(sortByAge)
     ).forEach(person->
        System.out.println(person));
```

Look: [Sort user defined object on multiple fields – Comparator (lambda stream)](http://www.makeinjava.com/sort-object-multiple-fields-properties-comparator-interface-lambda-stream-java-8/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Comparator` and then put objects into `Collection`,  then `Collections.sort();`

```
class Person {

    String fname;
    String lname;
    int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public Person(String fname, String lname, int age) {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fname + "," + lname + "," + age;
    }
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new java.util.ArrayList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person("abc3", "def3", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("abc2", "def2", 32));
        persons.add(new Person("abc1", "def1", 65));
        persons.add(new Person("abc4", "def4", 10));
        System.out.println(persons);
        Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Person t, Person t1) {
                return t.getAge() - t1.getAge();
            }
        });
        System.out.println(persons);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can exploit the fact that `Collections.sort()` (or `Arrays.sort()`) is stable (it doesn't reorder elements that are equal) and use a `Comparator` to sort by age first and then another one to sort by name.

In this specific case this isn't a very good idea but if you have to be able to change the sort order in runtime, it might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generic serial Comparator to sort collections by multiple fields.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
* @author MaheshRPM
*/
public class SerialComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
List<String> sortingFields;

public SerialComparator(List<String> sortingFields) {
    this.sortingFields = sortingFields;
}

public SerialComparator(String... sortingFields) {
    this.sortingFields = Arrays.asList(sortingFields);
}

@Override
public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        for (String sortingField : sortingFields) {
            if (result == 0) {
                Object value1 = FieldUtils.readField(o1, sortingField, true);
                Object value2 = FieldUtils.readField(o2, sortingField, true);
                if (value1 instanceof Comparable && value2 instanceof Comparable) {
                    Comparable comparable1 = (Comparable) value1;
                    Comparable comparable2 = (Comparable) value2;
                    result = comparable1.compareTo(comparable2);
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot compare non Comparable fields. " + value1.getClass()
                            .getName() + " must implement Comparable<" + value1.getClass().getName() + ">");
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.sort(persons, new PersonComparator());



import java.util.Comparator;

public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<? extends Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        if(null == o1 || null == o2  || null == o1.getName() || null== o2.getName() ){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }else{
            int nameComparisonResult = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            if(0 == nameComparisonResult){
                return o1.getAge()-o2.getAge();
            }else{
                return nameComparisonResult;
            }
        }
    }
}


class Person{
    int age; String name;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Updated version:

```
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<? extends Person> {

   @Override
   public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {

      int nameComparisonResult = o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
      return 0 == nameComparisonResult?o1.getAge()-o2.getAge():nameComparisonResult;

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a class `Book` like this:

```
package books;

public class Book {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer number;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "book{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", number=" + number +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' + '\n' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

sorting main class with mock objects

```
package books;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        Book b = new Book();

        Book c = new Book();

        Book d = new Book();

        Book e = new Book();

        Book f = new Book();

        Book g = new Book();
        Book g1 = new Book();
        Book g2 = new Book();
        Book g3 = new Book();
        Book g4 = new Book();




        b.setId(1);
        b.setNumber(12);
        b.setName("gk");

        c.setId(2);
        c.setNumber(12);
        c.setName("gk");

        d.setId(2);
        d.setNumber(13);
        d.setName("maths");

        e.setId(3);
        e.setNumber(3);
        e.setName("geometry");

        f.setId(3);
        f.setNumber(34);
        b.setName("gk");

        g.setId(3);
        g.setNumber(11);
        g.setName("gk");

        g1.setId(3);
        g1.setNumber(88);
        g1.setName("gk");
        g2.setId(3);
        g2.setNumber(91);
        g2.setName("gk");
        g3.setId(3);
        g3.setNumber(101);
        g3.setName("gk");
        g4.setId(3);
        g4.setNumber(4);
        g4.setName("gk");





        List<Book> allBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

        allBooks.add(b);
        allBooks.add(c);
        allBooks.add(d);
        allBooks.add(e);
        allBooks.add(f);
        allBooks.add(g);
        allBooks.add(g1);
        allBooks.add(g2);
        allBooks.add(g3);
        allBooks.add(g4);



        System.out.println(allBooks.size());


        Collections.sort(allBooks, new Comparator<Book>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Book t, Book t1) {
                int a =  t.getId()- t1.getId();

                if(a == 0){
                    int a1 = t.getNumber() - t1.getNumber();
                    return a1;
                }
                else
                    return a;
            }
        });
        System.out.println(allBooks);

    }


   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it's ugly to write the compartor inside the Person class in this case. Did it like this:

```
public class Person implements Comparable <Person> {

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int BirthDay) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = BirthDay;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        // default compareTo
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + age + "";
    }

    public static class firstNameComperator implements Comparator<Person> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            return o1.firstName.compareTo(o2.firstName);
        }
    }

    public static class lastNameComperator implements Comparator<Person> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            return o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastName);
        }
    }

    public static class ageComperator implements Comparator<Person> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            return o1.age - o2.age;
        }
    }
}
public class Test {
    private static void print() {
       ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Person("Diana", "Agron", 31));
        list.add(new Person("Kay", "Panabaker", 27));
        list.add(new Person("Lucy", "Hale", 28));
        list.add(new Person("Ashley", "Benson", 28));
        list.add(new Person("Megan", "Park", 31));
        list.add(new Person("Lucas", "Till", 27));
        list.add(new Person("Nicholas", "Hoult", 28));
        list.add(new Person("Aly", "Michalka", 28));
        list.add(new Person("Adam", "Brody", 38));
        list.add(new Person("Chris", "Pine", 37));
        Collections.sort(list, new Person.lastNameComperator());
        Iterator<Person> it = list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) 
            System.out.println(it.next().toString()); 
     }  
}
```

Comment: It is really not recommended as a pattern to bind a class to a specific comparator.