# how to show the list data in ascending order?

Tags: java, list, collections

Hi i am having the data on table in one field "ByYear" it contain the data years like 2005-2006, and the field type is varchar(10), the table data contains the following list... now my requirement was, i have to show the ByYear field data in Combo box in accending order on my Jsp page, here we can take value for accending by first year(2005 among 2005-2009). ru get the point?...... here i am showing the data of my table

```
ByYear
---------
2009-2010
2010-2011
2006-2009
2007-2009
2009-2010
2010-2011
2011-2012
2010-2011
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.sort(list, implementation of comparator)`

- [Check similar implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/java-sort-problem-by-two-fields/4805618#4805618)

Comment: can u give the discription about that implementation of comparator

Comment: Comparator is an interface . . [more](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) check the link too from post ,

Comment: can u send me an example code for that which matches for my requirement

Comment: I have pointed to example, you can easily construct the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to writing a custom comparator would be to create your own subclass which implements `Comparable` and then define a `compareTo` method as detailed [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10).

I personally prefer implementing a `compareTo`, as it allows you to use the various sorts built into other classes, rather than being restricted to only your `Comparator` class.