# Collections.sort in java for any class

Tags: java, class, sorting, collections

Java class problem

In C++ if we add some class objects to vector , we can sort the list by specifying some functions like operator<() or operator==() or operator!=.

What do we need to do in java for Collections.sort to work according to our wishes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You implement [`Comparable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

From the docs for [`Collections.sort`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29):

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

Alternatively, if you *don't* control the element type (e.g. you've got a `List<String>` and you want to apply a custom sort order) you implement [`Comparator<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass that in as an extra parameter to `Collections.sort`

Comment: I don't get why the javadoc for the method isn't the first place people check to find an answer!

Comment: Implementing a basic `Comparator` should be under the FAQ section of Java.

Answer (score 3):

Your class needs to implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in order for `sort` to work.

Answer (score 2):

Let your class implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) - typically you just override the compare method which returns an int, +ve, 0 or -ve to indicate "greater than", "the same" or "less than" for whatever definitions of these you choose. See another of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/java-sort-problem-by-two-fields/4805676#4805676) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can either implement Comparable or you can pass a Comparator to [Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)