# Sort an array with two arguments

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I already know how to sort an ArrayList but I wanna know if this is possible to sort an Array with two arguments like: I have an array 5 same objects with a float and a String in it like that:

```
- object 1 : 0 "DD"
- object 2 : 3 "FF"
- object 3 : 1 "GG"
- object 4 : 2 "AA"
- object 5 : 1 "AA"
```

And I want sort them like that:

```
- object 1 : 0 "DD"
- object 5 : 1 "AA"
- object 3 : 1 "GG"
- object 4 : 2 "AA"
- object 2 : 3 "FF"
```

Is it possible to sort them with a comparator by multiplying the `Float.compare()` and the `String.compare()` ?
or do you need to sort them first with the `Float.compare()` and then create sub-arrays to compare with the `String.compare()` ?

Comment: A mixture of `regex` and `sorting` will suffice.Use `:` as the separator in `String.split()` and then sort those arrays using `Arrays.sort()`!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java sort problem by two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/java-sort-problem-by-two-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. You just need a comparator that compares elements by their float value and, if their float value are equal, compares them by their string value:

```
public class FooComparator implements Comparator<Foo> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Foo f1, Foo f2) {
        int result = Float.compare(f1.getFloatValue(), f2.getFloatValue());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = f1.getStringValue().compareTo(f2.getStringValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Java 8 can even do that for you:

```
Comparator<Foo> c = Comparator.comparingDouble(Foo::getFloatValue)
                              .thenComparing(Foo::getStringValue);
```

Comment: +1 From Acache Commons I founded useful `ChainComparator` https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparatorChain.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your class as [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
public MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
    private float f;
    private String s;

    @Override
    public int compare (MyClass other) {
       int first = Float.compare(f, other.f);
       if (first != 0) {
           return first;
       }

       return s.compare(other.s);
    }
}
```

And then just call `Arrays.sort(myList)`.