# Collections.sort(), gives "unchecked or unsafe operation" Error?

Tags: java, collections

I get the error from Java Version 8: "uses unchecked or unsafe operations".

It seems like the problem is comming from `Collections.sort()`, but what is the problem? I've checked the Java Doc and everything seems to be fine, except that the argument is a `List`, but `ArrayList` is a `List` as far as I'm concerned?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Driver
{
    public static void test() 
    {
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person("Hans", "Car License"));
        persons.add(new Person("Adam", "Motorcycle License"));
        persons.add(new Person("Tom", "Car License"));
        persons.add(new Person("Kasper", "Car License"));

        System.out.println(persons);        
        Collections.sort(persons);   
        System.out.println(persons);

        System.out.println(Collections.max(persons));
        System.out.println(Collections.min(persons));
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort by two fields in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java)

Comment: And you forgot the most important part: show us the code of class `Person`

Comment: @JaeHeonLee, disagreed. The question is about compiler warning, not about how to sort.

Comment: Have a look at [Generics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) more of an idea of what's going on

Answer (score 11):

I suspect your class `Person` is declared this way:

```
class Person implements Comparable {
    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Change it to

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Do not use [rawtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/4856258).

Comment: Good answer. Please also explain shortly/link why using rawtypes should be avoided?

Comment: @RobAu, added link to the canonical do-not-use-rawtypes SO question.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when the compiler is not able to check that the collection is used in a type-safe way, using [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html). So you need to specify the type of objects you are storing in your collection.

As Tagir has pointed out that you are probably not providing the type when you are declaring your class `Person`, so the compiler is giving you the error. If you want a more detailed information you can recompile with the `"-Xlint:unchecked"` switch.