# How to sort a specific element of an object array

Tags: java, compareto, arrayobject

```
new Flight("Philadelphia", "Las Vegas", "Southwest", new GregorianCalendar(2007, 1, 12, 5, 0, 0),new GregorianCalendar(2007, 1, 12, 10, 0, 0))


new Flight("Trenton", "Blacksburg", "Trans-National Air", new GregorianCalendar(2007, 7, 11, 13, 30, 0), new GregorianCalendar(2007, 8, 11, 14, 30, 0)),
```

This is my Flight Object 1 & 2, there are many more inside an object array called flight. Recently I sorted the list be source city and departure time.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to sort an array of objects, by departure & arrival time.

This is all using the comparison method.

Could someone show me some code, sorting the two objects by departure & arrival time, or get me started I'm kinda stumped here.

Comment: Take a look at [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-). You should always look into jdk first before trying to write a utility method. Plenty of them are already there.

Comment: accept the answer please if that solved your problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method

```
Collections.sort(flight, Flight.getDepartureTime()); //First argument is name of the list
```

and

```
Collections.sort(flight, Flight.getArrivalTime());
```

Or you can use [Arrays.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) method like this:

```
Arrays.sort(flight, Flight.getDepartureTime()); //First argument is name of the array
```

and

```
Arrays.sort(flight, Flight.getArrivalTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `Comparable` interface in your `Flight` class, then override the `compareTo()` method after that you can do comparing inside.

Comment: Man!!! Next time you edit a post, make sure the comment is not `ooooooooooooooooooooooo`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can accomplish this using `Collections.sort,` and by defining a `compareTo` method for your object, as seen in this answer: [How to sort by two fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java)