# How to put my displayed Circles on my canvas in an array from the smallest X and Y position on the screen to the largest X and Y position JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

How to put my Circles in an array from the smallest X and Y position on the screen to the largest X and Y position?

I tried several solutions but nothing helped so far.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    Circle abcd = (Circle) root.getChildren().get(35-i);
    Circle cir1 = (Circle) root.getChildren().get(i);

    if(abcd.getCenterY() < cir1.getCenterY())
        if ( abcd.getCenterX()  < cir1.getCenterX() ) {
            abcd = cir1;
        }
        chronologisch.add(abcd);
    }
```

chronologisch is an ArrayList in this context.

With this code i get the following output when debugging:

> 0 = {Circle@2967} "Circle[centerX=305.0, centerY=225.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xffe100ff]"
>       1 = {Circle@2968} "Circle[centerX=260.0, centerY=225.0, radius=15.0, fill=0x00bbe2ff]"
>       2 = {Circle@2969} "Circle[centerX=215.0, centerY=225.0, radius=15.0, fill=0x00bbe2ff]"
>       3 = {Circle@2970} "Circle[centerX=170.0, centerY=225.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xffe100ff]"
>       4 = {Circle@2971} "Circle[centerX=125.0, centerY=225.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xffe100ff]"
>       5 = {Circle@2972} "Circle[centerX=80.0, centerY=225.0, radius=15.0, fill=0x91eb4cff]"
>       6 = {Circle@2973} "Circle[centerX=305.0, centerY=180.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xff7300ff]"
>       7 = {Circle@2974} "Circle[centerX=260.0, centerY=180.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xe02ca2ff]"
>       8 = {Circle@2975} "Circle[centerX=215.0, centerY=180.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xff6d7eff]"
>       9 = {Circle@2925} "Circle[centerX=170.0, centerY=180.0, radius=15.0, fill=0x91eb4cff]"
>       10 = {Circle@2976} "Circle[centerX=305.0, centerY=135.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xff7300ff]"
>       11 = {Circle@2977} "Circle[centerX=260.0, centerY=135.0, radius=15.0, fill=0x00bbe2ff]"
>       12 = {Circle@2978} "Circle[centerX=215.0, centerY=135.0, radius=15.0, fill=0x00bbe2ff]"
>       13 = {Circle@2979} "Circle[centerX=170.0, centerY=135.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xffe100ff]"
>       14 = {Circle@2980} "Circle[centerX=125.0, centerY=135.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xe02ca2ff]"
>       15 = {Circle@2981} "Circle[centerX=80.0, centerY=135.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xff7300ff]"
>       16 = {Circle@2982} "Circle[centerX=305.0, centerY=90.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xff6d7eff]"
>       17 = {Circle@2983} "Circle[centerX=260.0, centerY=90.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xe02ca2ff]"
>       18 = {Circle@2984} "Circle[centerX=215.0, centerY=90.0, radius=15.0, fill=0x91eb4cff]"
>       19 = {Circle@2985} "Circle[centerX=170.0, centerY=90.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xff7300ff]"
>       20 = {Circle@2986} "Circle[centerX=125.0, centerY=90.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xff7300ff]"
>       21 = {Circle@2980} "Circle[centerX=125.0, centerY=135.0, radius=15.0, fill=0xe02ca2ff]"

as you can see the values are not in chronological order.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: chronological order means time order

Comment: I would add your x y values together then sort your Array List.

Comment: [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) the list, according to whatever order you want the circles to be in.

Comment: I would take a look at this answer about [sorting using Comparators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805676/2650847).