# best way for sorting some arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have some array:

```
trade_prices[n]
trade_volumes[n]
trade_dates[n]
trade_tickers[n]
```

and I want to sort them by `tickers` and then by `dates`.

how can I sort them?

Comment: it can be done by for loops. but: 1- I don't know how (exactly) and 2- I don't know if it's the best way.

Comment: maybe it can be done by 2 for loops one after another. instead of two loops inside each other. I mean one time I can sort them by dates and other time by tickers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you should rethink the design. I think creating a class for these properties and having a collection of the class type is better:

```
class Trade
{
    double price;
    double volume;
    Date date;
    String tickers;
}
```

Then for sorting implement the `Comparator` interface. An example, after you create the class could be: [How to sort by two fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4805606/6400526)

Another option, as mentioned by saka1029, is to use [Comparator's functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) of `Comparator.comparing` and `Comparator.thenComparing` on the steam of the class's objects.

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosein - did this help you solve the problem?

Comment: Hi, I'm working on it. I'm new in java (and also in programming) so it takes time

Answer (score 3):

Define inner class `Trade` like this.

```
int n = 10;
int[] trade_prices = new int[n];
int[] trade_volumes = new int[n];
Date[] trade_dates = new Date[n];
String[] trade_tickers = new String[n];
// fill data...
class Trade {
    final int i; 
    Trade(int i) { this.i = i; } 
    int price() { return trade_prices[i]; } 
    int volume() { return trade_volumes[i]; } 
    Date date() { return trade_dates[i]; } 
    String ticker() { return trade_tickers[i]; }
}
Trade[] trades = IntStream.range(0, n)
    .mapToObj(Trade::new)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Trade::ticker).thenComparing(Trade::date))
    .toArray(Trade[]::new);
```

Then you can get sorted first price as `trades[0].price()`.
Original arrays are not changed.

Comment: The use of `Comparator.comparing` is nice but the class's implementation for accessing external arrays without checking the indexes and nulls is a very bad practice IMO

Answer (score 0):

Make a class with constructors and methods in it and declare your arrays as global. You can write a function to sort your arrays.