# Method expected to compare by two fields with comparator but orders just by one

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

I was looking for a way to implement a Comparator for comparing products by name and price. I've found a lot of useful information here [How to sort by two fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java) and have implemented my comparator.

It compares product names correctly but the prices are not in the right order. *I'm expecting to have names in alphabetical order and prices in ascending order.* 
How is it possible to achieve that? What am I missing here?

Here is what I've made so far:

**A method to compare by name and price**

```
public static List<BaseProduct> compareNamesAndPrices(List<BaseProduct> baseProducts) {
    Comparator<BaseProduct> productComparator = Comparator.comparing(BaseProduct::getProductName)
            .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(BaseProduct::getPrice));
    return baseProducts.stream()
            .sorted(productComparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Testing the method**

```
List<BaseProduct> sortedProductsList = StaticUtils.compareNamesAndPrices(products);
for (BaseProduct product : sortedProductsList) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Product name: %s  -> Price: %s", product.getProductName(), product.getPrice().toString()));
}
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
Product name: Bananas  -> Price: 45
Product name: Galaxy 7 phone  -> Price: 400
Product name: Xiaomi Mi5  -> Price: 370
```

Comment: what the output should be? The output you share are logic, i don't see where is the problem here

Comment: But the output is sorted by name and price! The sorting by price is only relevant for products with the same name.

Comment: I'm expecting to have names in alphabetical order and prices in ascending order.

Comment: If you sort by two fields then the second field is only looked at if the first is equal (i.e. the first compare yields 0). This is never the case with your inputs, since you sort by name first and all names differ

Comment: Show expected output and explain the difference between it and the current output.

Answer (score 1):

When you compose comparators with `thenComparing` on top of the previous comparator, it will only ever be considered if and only if the previous comparator finds at least two equal elements by the given sort key.

Looking at your output there are no products which have the same name, for that reason the prices are not considered at all.

Considering you've mentioned:

> I'm expecting to have names in alphabetical order and prices in
>   ascending order.

the simple matter of fact is, this *cannot* be done without losing the ordering of the Product names or the ordering of the Prizes.

The best you can do is to sort the Products either by name or by prizes when appropriate.