# Writing a custom comparator for a C++ map which has a custom defined key

Tags: c++, comparator

I'm trying to write a custom comparator for a C++ map which has a custom defined key.

```
struct key { int year; int no; };
map<key, detail, compare> details_map;
```

if the `year` values are equal, it must compare the `no` values.

I'm trying to figure out a way to write a comparator that can compare both values. So far, I am only able to write a comparator which compares one value.

```
struct Compare{bool operator()(const key &lhs,const key &rhs)const{return lhs.year<rhs.year;}}
```

Can someone please explain how a comparator works in a `map`?

Also, is it possible to write the comparator as a function?

Comment: Use the conditional operators to compare more than one values, like you'd do in a normal function.

Comment: A corresponding Java question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java

Comment: in c++ it is different than in Java. In c++ comparator is effectively "operator less", while in Java it is 3-way comparison. Analog in C++ is "operator spaceship", but it is only since c++ 20 and still std::map expects sort of "operator less" as Compare template argument.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside your `operator()`, simply compare the `no` values if the `year` values are equal:

```
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const key &lhs, const key &rhs) const {
        if (lhs.year == rhs.year) {
            return lhs.no < rhs.no;
        }
        return lhs.year < rhs.year;
    }
};
```

And yes, a comparator can be implemented as a standalone function instead:

```
bool Compare (const key &lhs, const key &rhs) {
    if (lhs.year == rhs.year) {
        return lhs.no < rhs.no;
    }
    return lhs.year < rhs.year;
}
```

Alternatively, you can have your comparator use `std::tie()` to compare your key fields.  See [@Jarod42's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642192/65863).

Though, it would make more sense to implement `operator<` for your `key` type instead:

```
struct key {
    int year;
    int no;

    bool operator<(const key &rhs) const {
        if (year == rhs.year) {
            return no < rhs.no;
        }
        return year < rhs.year;
    }
};
```

Or

```
struct key {
    int year;
    int no;
};

bool operator<(const key &lhs, const key &rhs) {
    if (lhs.year == rhs.year) {
        return lhs.no < rhs.no;
    }
    return lhs.year < rhs.year;
}
```

Then you don't need a separate comparator:

```
map<key, detail> details_map;
```

Comment: @ÖöTiib actually, I was thinking of `std::tie()`, I just couldn't remember it until I saw Jarod's answer

Comment: From your solution, can we search for a key in the map using this 1 line of code " if( details_map.find( key_1 ) != details_map.end() ) " ? Or do we need to write any new function to compare the keys in this case ? -- Thank you.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Yes, with a proper comparator implemented (using any of the techniques shown), `find()` will work.

Comment: Thanks. The find() method works when I write the comparator operator< as you suggested. However, I wonder why find() works if I do not write the comparator operator== or operator!= and I only need to write the operator<  ? Is it because the compiler is smart enough so that from the operator<, it can deduce and construct the operator== and operator!= on its own ? - Thanks.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 "*I wonder why find() works if I do not write the comparator operator== or operator!= and I only need to write the operator<?*" - because `std::map` simply does not use those other operators, it performs comparisons only in terms of `operator<`. "*Is it because the compiler is smart enough so that from the operator<, it can deduce and construct the operator== and operator!= on its own?*" - no. The compiler has nothing to do with this. This is strictly an implementation detail of how `std::map` is designed to work

Answer (score 4):

`std::tie` allows simple lexicographical comparison:

```
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const key& lhs, const key& rhs) const {
        return std::tie(lhs.year, lhs.no) < std::tie(rhs.year, rhs.no);
    }
};
```

Method/function `as_tuple` might be interesting to avoid some repetitions:

```
struct key { int year; int no; };

auto as_tuple(const key& k) { return std::tie(k.year, k.no); }

struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const key& lhs, const key& rhs) const {
        return as_tuple(lhs) < as_tuple(rhs);
    }
};
```