# Sort by count in spring mvc, for a OneToMany variable

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have two classes in my spring application:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "venue_fk")
    private Venue venue;
    // Setters, getters...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "venues")
public class Venue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();
    // Setters, getters...
}
```

The thing I want to do is to write a method in VenueService that returns `Iterable<Venue>` and venue objects appear in this Iterable based on how many events they have (DESC) and then venue name(ASC), the more events one venue has, the earlier it appears.

E.g. I have three venues, venueA has 3 events registered with it, venueB has 3 events registered with it, and venueC has 4 events registered with it, then the method `findAllVenuesByNoOfEvents()` should return `Iterable<Venue>` in the order venueC, venueA, venueB.

I'm new to spring and I'm really don't know how to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java