# Java sort HashMap by highest value, then lowest key

Tags: java, hashmap

Lets say I have a `HashMap<Recipe, Integer>` where Recipe is a class with 2 integer parameters. We can call them lemons and sugar. I want to get the key (which is a Recipe) in the HashMap that has the highest corresponding value. As a secondary sorting method, in case it contains multiple Recipes with the same value. It should return the Recipe with the sum of sugar and lemons that is the lowest.

eg.

```
HashMap<Recipe, Integer> recipes = new HashMap<>();
recipes.put(new Recipe(5, 3), 10); // 5 is lemons, 3 is sugar
recipes.put(new Recipe(8, 8), 15);
recipes.put(new Recipe(1, 2), 15);
Recipe bestRecipe - recipes.getBestRecipe();
// bestRecipe.getLemons() would be 1
// bestRecipe.getSugar() would be 2
// because it has the highest value (15) with the lowest sum of sugar and lemons (1+2=3)
```

How would I go about doing that? I know I can get the largest value with Collections.max(recipes.values()) but how would I find the largest value with the lowest sum of lemons and sugar?

Comment: Do your `Recipe` objects have equals and hashcode?  What is the criteria of comparison?

Comment: what is the expected output??

Comment: Just write a `Comparator` that compares `Map.Entry` objects according to your logic.

Comment: You can use this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805676/259889

Comment: Yep I figured it out. Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a stream of the map entries and use the `max` method to get the max element sorted by a comparator.

The comparator logic is as follows:

1. It sorts by the map's value.
2. In case of a tie, it *reverse* sorts by the sum of lemons and sugars of a recipe. This means that the values would be sorted from greatest to lowest.

---

```
Optional<Recipe> bestRecipe = recipes.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt((Map.Entry<Recipe, Integer> e) -> e.getValue())
                        .thenComparing(e -> e.getKey().getSugar() + e.getKey().getLemons(), 
                            Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the map and write your comparator for sorting then get the first element

```
recipes.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> {
             int v = e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
             if(v!=0) return v;
             Integer a = (e1.getKey().getLemons() + e1.getKey().getSuger());
             Integer b = (e2.getKey().getLemons() + e2.getKey().getSuger());
             return Integer.compare(a,b);
         })
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .findFirst().get();
```

Comment: This one seems to return the exact opposite haha. Dont worry though, Robby Cornelissen's answer worked. For me, it seemed to return the lowest value and the sugar+lemons was 40, which was the highest

Comment: @divadnebnahtan sorry by bad check now