# OrderBy under two criteria

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting

I am currently working on a user list requirement: all users (active and inactive) must be displayed, this list must be sorted by the most recent user edit date; so far I have done my job; However, I was recently asked for deleted users to appear at the bottom of the list. I really have no idea how to work it out, as I feel like they're mutually exclusive things. If anyone has any suggestions to fix this requirement I will be extremely grateful.

I am using Springboot, OrderBy function:

```
@Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() throws SQLException {
        List<User> users = (List<User>) this.userRepository.findAllByOrderByUpdatedAt();
        return users;

    }
```

Comment: This question has a number of helpful answers: [How to sort by two fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java)

Comment: You meant don't know how to delete the bottom of list from List Object or what?

Comment: Currently I have the list orderBy date, it is fine; but I don't know how to add to my current list deleted users in the bottom