# Find min amount in a list of objects using Java if there is a tie

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects. I need to find the minimum amount from a list of objects. But if there is a tie, then need to find the one with minimum Age. How to accomplish it using java 8?

```
class TestObject{
    private Double amount;
    private int age;
}

List<TestObject> objectList = getAllItems();
TestObject obj = objectList.stream()
            .min(Comparator
            .comparing(TestObject::getAmount))
            .get();
```

Comment: What is Bid class? Did you mean TestObject::getAmount?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort by two fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java)

Comment: yes.@kasptom Just updated it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To combine two fields in the comparator you can use the answer linked by Goion or use the [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)) function like this:

```java
TestObject obj = objectList
      .stream() 
      .min(Comparator.comparing(TestObject::getAmount)
                     .thenComparing(TestObject::getAge))
      .get();
```