# How to sort an ArrayList on more than one field

Tags: java, android

I have `ArrayList<Item> itemList`. The Class `Item` contains two fields: `char firstLetter` and `char secondLetter`.

If I wanted to sort `itemList` on `firstLetter`, the code would be

```
 Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
            char order1 = o1.getFirstLetter();
            char order2 = o2.getFirstLetter();
            return Character.compare(order1,order2);
        }
    });
```

However, within the same sorting operation I want `itemList` also to be sorted according to `secondLetter`. So `items` that have the same value for `firstLetter` are sorted among them according to their value for `secondLetter`. How should the above code be modified?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to sort by two fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        char order1 = o1.getFirstLetter();
        char order2 = o2.getFirstLetter();

        char order3 = o1.getSecondLetter();
        char order4 = o2.getSecondLetter();

        String first = String.valueOf(order1)+String.valueOf(order3)
        String second= String.valueOf(order2)+String.valueOf(order4)

        return first.compareTo(second);
    }
});
```

An embedded solution should look like this:

```
Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        char order1 = o1.getFirstLetter();
        char order2 = o2.getFirstLetter();

        char order3 = o1.getSecondLetter();
        char order4 = o2.getSecondLetter();

        int compare = Character.compare(order1,order2);

        if(compare == 0){
            return Character.compare(order3,order4);
        } else {
            return compare;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't even have to try it to know that this brilliant hack will work. I was looking for an embedded solution, but this certainly will do the job just as well. Thanks.

Comment: @RedKnight If this solution has helped you please accept and upvote it so that it can help others in the community. Thanks

Comment: Can't. My reputation is too low.

Comment: @RedKnight You can't upvote it but you can surely accept it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: You're right. Done. Your embedded solution looks great too.